# Django 1.6 and ckeditor uploading image

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

installed Django 1.6.1 over 1.5, update Pillow, PIL, django-ckeditor and django-ckeditor-updated, remove default from url. When I want to upload a picture I see this:

```
ImportError at /ckeditor/upload/

No module named image

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    mysiteaddress/ckeditor/upload/?CKEditor=id_about&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en
Django Version:     1.6.1
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

No module named image

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ckeditor/image_processing.py in get_backend, line 10
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
Python Version:     2.7.5
```

someone can help?

Comment: just collectstatic again (rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

Along with trying collect static, you are not supposed to have django-ckeditor and django-ckeditor-updated in the same project. See installation notes.

https://github.com/shaunsephton/django-ckeditor#installation